# Configuring tomcat and hosting a java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war, web-hosting

I have copied the war file of my java web application (Inside system A containing the hosting server) in the webapps folder of tomcat 7. What are the steps to access this application from "System B" given that I know ip address of the "A". What are the steps to complete the hosting procedure and make sure my tomcat is properly configured.

Comment: check context of your war file and hit that. like http://`AIPADDRES:port`/`yourwebappcontext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the name of the webapplication in the url which is usually the name of the war file (without the `.war` extension).

```
http://<ip-comes-here>:<port>/<webappname>
```

E.g. if your `.war` file is named `myapp.war`, then you can access it at:

```
http://<ip-comes-here>:<port>/myapp
```

This can be overridden and there is a special `ROOT` webapp name (might come from `ROOT.war`) which will be available at the root of your host:

```
http://<ip>:<port>/
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Installing TOMCAT & Configuring:**

Install the tomcat from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/) :select the required version from download.

Setting the environment variable:

System Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables

> Variable Name : CATALINA_HOME
>   Variable Value: C:\TOMCAT 7.0.10 (your tomcat directory)

Check your port number in Tomcat--->conf--->server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" 
redirectPort="8443" />
```

Please note that your oracle is having a default port number 8080. Make sure no conflicts are there

Start the server(Go to the bin folder of tomcat and use startup.bat in windows and startup.sh for linux)

Then try the url in any web browser :

```
 http://localhost:portNumber/
```

If you get the tomcat homepage your tomcat is properly configured.

### **Deploying application war File :**

```
Step 1:stop tomcat(Go to the bin folder of tomcat and use shutdown.bat in windows and shutdown.sh for linux)
Step 2:move your war into "[tomcat install dir]/webapps"
Step 3:start tomcat
```

Then try to access your web application as explained in the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562779/3988992) in any web browser